# How to fix this error while running macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro which never had any issues before. Today when I try to run the macro it prompts 'License information for this component not found. You don't have an appropriate license to use this functionality in the design environment' (Error 429). And when I run the code itself. It says 'Activex component cn't create object'. The code begins as below

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateForEachLine()
Dim myPathTo As String
    myPathTo = "C:\Users\9418\Desktop\Work Files\Vending\April 1"
    Dim myFileSystemObject As Object
' The Activex component error debug highlights below line
    Set myFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Dim fileOut As Object
    Dim myFileName As String

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long

        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
                myFileName = Cells(i, 1) & ".txt"
                Set fileOut = myFileSystemObject.OpenTextFile(myFileName, 8, True)
                fileOut.write Cells(i, 2) & vbTab & Cells(i, 3) & vbTab & Cells(i, 4) & vbTab & Cells(i, 5) & vbNewLine
                fileOut.Close
            End If
        Next

    Set myFileSystemObject = Nothing
    Set fileOut = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have another macro-enabled file with different code and that works fine. Is it related to licensing of the microsoft product as I see when I go to File> Help it says product Activation required. Is this creating a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only object you are creating is in this line

```
 Set myFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

and the FileSystemObject is stored in scrrun.dll in c:\windows\system32

It is unlikely that there is a licence attached to it, but it is the start of a new financial year, so it's possible that there was some expiry data attached. I suspect however that in some way your code is attempting to run a different Scripting.FileSystemObject . Why not try early binding? In the vb editor, go to tools references and tick "Microsoft Scripting Runtime". Then replace the lines

```
 Dim myFileSystemObject As Object
Set myFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

with

```
 Dim myFileSystemObject as New FileSystemObject
```

and see if you still get the error